# Triangulating MultiPointZ points in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I'm working with MultiPointZ in QGIS and trying to create a polygon based on point distances. Is there a way to achieve this using QGIS ?

Comment: What sort of polygon? Why triangles? Is the Z value important?